# How to use the local editor for remote WP-CLI?

Tags: wordpress, vim

How can I use my **local** vim for remote wordpress management via [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/fr/)?

Currently this command opens vim on the remote machine, though I want my local vim used instead:

```
$ wp gf form edit 4 --ssh=remoteWP --path=\"/home/wp/disk/wordpress\"
```

I know how to edit remote files in vim using `scp:`, though since *wp-cli* overtakes opening the file (I think via `$EDITOR`) I'm wondering if these functions point to the right direction at all?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are using a local `wp` to manage remote WordPress installs via SSH. If yes and `wp` opens an SSH session for you then there's no way the remote machine could know anything about your local Vim.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @romainl, if you are entering the above command in your local terminal, you're most definitely using your local $editor to edit the forms.

`wp gf form edit` is just transferring the information over SSH and opening up a local $editor.

To verify that this is indeed happening, change your $EDITOR to `nano` or `gedit`, and check whether it opens up `nano` or `gedit`. This test will most likely work (but maynot be conclusive), as sometimes applications (such as `git`) can ignore the $EDITOR variable, and use define its own editor.